# Click All Buttons on Page

Tags: javascript, html, button, submit

I was wondering if anyone could help with a simple JavaScript code to click all buttons with the same value name/input name on a page?

They each share:

```
<input name="all" type="submit" value="Do All">
```

Here's a screenshot of the buttons: http://oi61.tinypic.com/2nqblnr.jpg

Maybe one should make a button that works as a "click all" button? This will be a chrome extension (for personal use), so I can't really go about changing the "do all" button's code.

I was having a hard time finding it on Google, and I'm fine with HTML/CSS but really terrible with JavaScript.

Comment: You probably don't want to use java for this task. Javascript is more appropriate.

Answer (score 9):

To click all the buttons on the page with the same name you can use getElementsByName() function and set it to a variable which will hold all the buttons in a NodeList then loop through the NodeList and call the `click()` event for each button.

For example:

```
   // Get all buttons with the name 'all' and store in a NodeList called 'buttons'
   var buttons = document.getElementsByName('all');

    // Loop through NodeList and call the click() function on each button
    for(var i = 0; i <= buttons.length; i++)  
       buttons[i].click();
```

Comment: Please add explanation. Your answer is currently being voted for deletion. Please do so to avoid future misunderstandings.

Comment: that should be abit better :)

Answer (score 3):

```js
// Select all buttons with class .btn
const inputBtns = document.querySelectorAll('[name="all"]');
// Select click all button
const clickAllBtn = document.querySelector('.click-all');

// Attach click handler to all input buttons
for(let i = 0; i < inputBtns.length; i++) {
 inputBtns[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
   alert(this.value);
  })
}

// Click all buttons, when user click .click-all button
clickAllBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  for(let i = 0; i < inputBtns.length; i++) {
   inputBtns[i].click();
  }
})
```

```html
<input name="all" type="submit" value="Do All 1">
<input name="all" type="submit" value="Do All 2">
<button type="button" class="click-all">
click all
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me assuming the of those elements had href="#show" or something similar

```
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('[href="#show"]');

for(var i = 0; i <= buttons.length; i++)  
   buttons[i].click();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('uArJ5e');

    // Loop through NodeList and call the click() function on each button
    for(var i = 0; i <= buttons.length; i++)  
       buttons[i].click();
```

This will click all buttons on google ;)

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you want to achieve :

jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/vqk2V/

Achieved using `.click()`[http://api.jquery.com/click/] method of jquery.

Answer (score 0):

With Java...maybe using Selenium. But you can use jquery (javascrpt's framework) so the code could be:

```
<scrpipt>
function ClickAllButtons()
{
    if($("input[type=button][name='someName']").length > 0)
    {
        $('input[type=button]').each(function(i){
        var $currentButton = $(this);
        $currentButton.click();
        });
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -3):

What you would want to do is create a class eg.

public class MyClass{
........
}

..and then create methods which do the processing that is done when you click your buttons.
Then call the methods with an object if your methods are non static in the specific buttons you require the method in.

Now you can create a button which calls all the methods you want to call and it will do what you are asking for.